# Generics and Interface issue

Tags: c#, generics, interface, implementation

Given the following class and interface:

```
public class Test<T>
{
}

public interface ITesting<T>
{
    Test<T> LoadTest();
}
```

I can add a class with the following:

```
public class TestManager : ITesting<object>
{
    #region ITesting

    public Test<object> LoadTest()
    {
        return new Test<object>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Which works fine and throws no errors. If I try to replace that class with the following:

```
public class TestDerived : Test<object>
{
}

public class TestDerivedManager : ITesting<object>
{
    #region ITesting

    public TestDerived LoadTest()
    {
        return new TestDerived();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I now get the following error:

```
Error   'TestDerivedManager' does not implement interface member 'ITesting.LoadTest()'. 'TestDerivedManager.LoadTest()' cannot implement 'ITesting.LoadTest()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Test'.
```

But to me it seems like this should work as `TestDerived` is `Test<object>`. I'm obviously not understanding something correctly here. Could someone possible point me to details on why this is incorrect? And possibly what I might do to correct it?

Comment: I note that this behaviour has nothing whatsoever to do with generics. If you had `interface I { Animal M(); } class C : I { public Giraffe M() { return new Giraffe(); } }` you'd get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you want is called return type covariance. It is a feature of c++ but not of c#, so you'll have to do what the error says.

I recommend you make an explicit interface implementation that calls your public method. That way you get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 6):

A `TestDerived` is a `Test<object>`, yes, but a `Test<object>` is *not* a `TestDerived`.

The contract says that `ITesting<object>` has a method that can return any `Test<object>`. Not just one special case (`TestDerived`).

To make your code work, change it as follows:

```
public class TestDerivedManager : ITesting<object>
{
    public Test<object> LoadTest()
    {
        return new TestDerived();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the return type of the method back to `Test<object>` and it should work.  The return type is part of the contract when implementing an interface.  You can still return the `TestDerived` since it is a `Test<object>`.

Comment: It would but I don't think it explains why it doesn't work when TestDerived is actually Test<Object>

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called "[return type covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)," and unfortunately is not supported by C#.  You can't override (or implement) a method with a different return type than the original signature, even if that return type derives from the original return type.

What you can do (which may or may not be a good idea) is implement the interface explicitly and have that call a public method that returns the narrower type you're looking for:

```
public class TestDerived : Test<object>
{
}

public class TestDerivedManager : ITesting<object>
{
  public TestDerived LoadTest()
  {
    return new TestDerived();
  }

  Test<object> ITesting<object>.LoadTest()
  {
    return this.LoadTest();
  }
}
```

That adds an extra layer of complication to your implementation, but it also gives you the public contract you're looking for, along with compatibility with the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has good technical answer but no one explain why. So I think I will give an illustration about interface.

The general way of interface programming is you should implement the exact method or property described in interface. Let's say that you has interface:

```
public interface ITesting<T>
{
    Test<T> LoadTest();
}
```

The usage of this interface in your consumer should be like this:

```
ITesting<object> testingLoader = GetTestingLoader();
Test<object> testingLoader.LoadTest();
```

If you access the object by using the interface, you don't know the implementation. You only know that the interface `ITesting<T>` will return `Test<T>` for the `LoadTest()` method.

It will come into sense when you see the consumer example above. You (and the compiler) don't (and won't) know that the interface `ITesting<object>` has a method `Test<object> LoadTest()` unless you declare it. And what will happen if you try to use an object that is implemented `ITesting<object>` but has no `Test<object> LoadTest()` method? It will error won't it?

This is following the [LSV principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Erhm, no, you are wrong. Talking about LSP: I should be able to treat a `TestDerivedManager` object as a `ITesting<object>`, call `LoadTest` on it and get a `Test<object>` (as the interface specifies). The implementation returns a `TestDerived`, which _is_ a `Test<object>`. So all is well, no LSP violation, and the code should just work. No erroring. Only caveat: some languages support it, but not C#.